# VBA Autosort with Formulas in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to create a 2 column table that automatically sorts keyword categories in Column A by their number of entries in Column B when a change is made to the cells. The goal is to create an error log for GMAT preparation where I can quickly view common keywords in my error entries.

The table looks like this:
[Keyword Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Ufi.jpg)

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("B1").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

I seem to be running into trouble because the cells in Column B are comprised of formulas that capture entries on other worksheets.

Is anyone aware of a way for me to retain these formulas and have the table automatically sort itself based on the resulting values?

Thanks much! I'm stumped.

Comment: you will want to use Worksheet_calculate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I probe further? 

To clarify, the formulas in these cells reference other worksheets to determine the number of keywords entered elsewhere in the workbook. 

For example: 

`=COUNTIF('Reading Comprehension'!C:C,"*Logical Predication*") + COUNTIF('Sentence Correction'!C:C,"*Logical Predication*") + COUNTIF('Critical Reasoning'!C:C,"*Logical Predication*")`
If i used worksheet_calculate, I would still need to preserve this functionality.

Comment: A change in a cell due to a formula will not fire the Worksheet_change event.  Worksheet_Calculate will capture the change due to formula.

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining this fact. I understand now.